# Scala operator associativity (2nd parameter lists)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is it possible to call an apply function directly on the result of a method which takes a second parameter list (with an implicit arg)? Even with parentheses in the logical place, I get the same compile-time type error, which indicates it doesn't parse it as expected.

```
val x = Map(1 -> 2, 2->4, 3-> 6) //1

val y = x.map(_.swap) //2

y(4) //3

x.map(_.swap)(4) //4

((x.map(_.swap))(4) //5
```

Line 4 makes sense to not parse since the (4) easily appears to be the second parameter list for map(), but line 5, there is a set of ()'s around the .map expression, yet it still associates the (4) to the .map rather than the result of .map().

Is there a way to do lines 2 and 3 in one expression?

EDIT: I'm aware of .apply(), which is what the compiler will insert itself. Is there a way to do this without manually de-sugaring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are several possible solutions. 
All work by either satisfying the implicit parameter list or giving the compiler a hint that expression has ended and the `()`, read apply, is really the apply-method and no second argument list.

## 1. Calling `.apply()`

```
scala> Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6).map(_.swap).apply(4)
res7: Int = 2
```

## 2. Supplying the implicit directly

Another option is supplying the implicit directly

Example with breakout

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

scala> List(1).map(_ + 1)(breakOut)(0)
res38: Int = 2
```

I think the general problem is: You have to fill to provide the implicit for the `CanBuildFrom` to work properly or explicitly state that you want to call apply and not fill the second parameter list.

You can find more in http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout. Opposing to the name the secCanBuildFrom works.

Comment: I'm aware of "apply". I was looking for something that doesn't require manually "de-sugaring"; in other words, something that follows normal composition of expressions (as combining lines 2 and 3)

Comment: `(breakOut)` won't work for the OP's example because the `Map` is lost.  It gets turned into a Seq of tuples.

Comment: the example is just an example; i.e. it is not important that it is a `Map` or that `.map()` is called. It's only important that it's a function which has a second parameter list with an implicit arg and the result type supports `apply`

Comment: `;` doesn't work as intended. The `;` separates expressions. The point of the `(4)` in the original code is to retrieve the value from the Map with the key of `4`.

Comment: Why doesn't surrounding with parentheses indicate to the compiler that the expression (`.map()`) has ened? It should.

Comment: True. Thanks for pointing this out. Adpated the answer and deleted the faulty `;`-solution.